# Как сделать бесконечную прокрутку?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Как сделать бесконечную прокрутку?

```js
$("#right").click(function() {
  $(".slide").animate({
    "left": "+=100px"
  }, "slow");
});

$("#left").click(function() {
  $(".slide").animate({
    "left": "-=100px"
  }, "slow");
});
```

```css
.content {
  width: 100px;
  height: 160px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  left: 100px;
}
.slide {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  background-color: #abc;
  left: 0px;
  width: 300px;
  height: 160px;
}
.block {
  width: 100px;
  height: 160px;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="content">
  <div class="slide">
    <div class="block">1</div>
    <div class="block">2</div>
    <div class="block">3</div>
  </div>
</div>
<button id="left">&laquo;</button>
<button id="right">&raquo;</button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$(function() {
  (function go() {
    $('.slide').delay(1000).animate({
      left: '-=100'
    }, 1200, function() {
      $('.block:first').appendTo($(this))
      $(this).css({
        left: '0px'
      });
      go()
    })
  }())
})
```

```css
.content {
  width: 100px;
  height: 160px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  left: 100px;
}
.slide {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  background-color: #abc;
  left: 0px;
  width: 300px;
  height: 160px;
}
.block {
  width: 100px;
  height: 160px;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="content">
  <div class="slide">
    <div class="block" style="background-color:red;">1</div>
    <div class="block" style="background-color:green;">2</div>
    <div class="block" style="background-color:Yellow;">3</div>
    <div class="block" style="background-color:DeepPink;">4</div>
    <div class="block" style="background-color:MediumBlue;">5</div>
  </div>
</div>
```